# pulling large amount of data from AX to mobile app

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, axapta

our team have developed the mobile app using `Xamarin Forms` for field sales users that fetches the data related to customer, sales order , products etc from the `AX` using the `AIF webserices` over

The problem that we are currently facing is related to the amount of data that we are pulling it from AX for product and sales order entities.

Rite now our webservice is pulling **6 thousand** products data that has around 10 fields

**product json sample**

```
{
        "itemDimensions": [],
        "itemGroup": "Foam Rolls",
        "itemName": "48\" X 550' 1/8\" FOAM ROLLS",
        "itemNumber": ".125FM48X858",
        "searchName": ".125FM48X447",
        "siteId": "",
        "type": "Product",
        "unit": "ROLL",
        "variantName": "",
        "variantNumber": "",
        "warehouseId": ""
    },
```

and for sales order we are fetching around **2 thousand** of data but it has more nested json data , in following json you can see that we are fetching

1. Order details
2. Array of Attachment details
3. Array of Notes details
4. Array of product details

so this is  bulking up the single json element and eventually the entire json response. Due to this our app is getting request timeout even after setting timeout interval of 5 mins and dropping the performance down as it takes 30 mins just to sync product and sales order data into mobile app as part of initial sync process. so i am looking for the solution where we can fasten the data sync process but implementing something on the server end that streams the data into mobile app at a faster pace.

if anyone can suggest better approach or architecture to resolve then issue would be nice.

**Sales order json sample**

```
{
  "cashDiscount": "S10D-.5%",
  "chargeTotal": 0,
  "confirmedShipmentDate": "2019-01-10",
  "contactId": 0,
  "currency": "USD",
  "customerId": 878787,
  "deliveryMode": "BJLTL",
  "deliverylocation": 8887788,
  "description": "",
  "listAttachments": [
    {
      "fileMimeType": "",
      "filePath": "",
      "name": "",
      "timestamp": "2019-02-08T16:44:08.000Z",
      "type": "Pick"
    },
    {
      "fileMimeType": "",
      "filePath": "",
      "name": "",
      "timestamp": "2019-02-08T16:44:13.000Z",
      "type": "Invoice"
    }
  ],
  "listNotes": [
    {
      "description": "",
      "mNoteId": null,
      "noteId": 5637334180,
      "notes": "UPS COLLECT ACCT #F59056",
      "restriction": "Internal"
    }
  ],
  "listProducts": [
    {
      "deliveryMode": "BJLTL",
      "lineDiscount": 0,
      "linePercent": 0,
      "mProductId": null,
      "netAmount": 1620,
      "priceApprovalStatus": "Open",
      "productId": "23ECTB60X4455",
      "productPrice": 2.7,
      "quantity": 600,
      "salesLineStatus": "Invoiced",
      "salesOrderLineId": 5637161102,
      "siteId": "GLENVW1",
      "unit": "EA",
      "wareHouseId": "28"
    },
    {
      "deliveryMode": "BJLTL",
      "lineDiscount": 0,
      "linePercent": 0,
      "mProductId": null,
      "netAmount": 651,
      "priceApprovalStatus": "Open",
      "productId": "23ECTB4455",
      "productPrice": 2.17,
      "quantity": 300,
      "salesLineStatus": "Invoiced",
      "salesOrderLineId": 5637161103,
      "siteId": "GLENVW1",
      "unit": "EA",
      "wareHouseId": "28"
    },
    {
      "deliveryMode": "BJLTL",
      "lineDiscount": 0,
      "linePercent": 0,
      "mProductId": null,
      "netAmount": 972,
      "priceApprovalStatus": "Open",
      "productId": "23ECTB3654545",
      "productPrice": 1.62,
      "quantity": 600,
      "salesLineStatus": "Invoiced",
      "salesOrderLineId": 5637161105,
      "siteId": "GLENVW1",
      "unit": "EA",
      "wareHouseId": "28"
    },
    {
      "deliveryMode": "BJLTL",
      "lineDiscount": 0,
      "linePercent": 0,
      "mProductId": null,
      "netAmount": 1038,
      "priceApprovalStatus": "Open",
      "productId": "23ECTB488787",
      "productPrice": 1.73,
      "quantity": 600,
      "salesLineStatus": "Invoiced",
      "salesOrderLineId": 5637161106,
      "siteId": "GLENVW1",
      "unit": "EA",
      "wareHouseId": "28"
    },
    {
      "deliveryMode": "BJLTL",
      "lineDiscount": 0,
      "linePercent": 0,
      "mProductId": null,
      "netAmount": 222.06,
      "priceApprovalStatus": "Open",
      "productId": "2CFS38X700",
      "productPrice": 74.02,
      "quantity": 3,
      "salesLineStatus": "Invoiced",
      "salesOrderLineId": 5637161107,
      "siteId": "GLENVW1",
      "unit": "ROLL",
      "wareHouseId": "28"
    },
    {
      "deliveryMode": "BJLTL",
      "lineDiscount": 0,
      "linePercent": 0,
      "mProductId": null,
      "netAmount": 217.14,
      "priceApprovalStatus": "Open",
      "productId": "2SWS52X178787",
      "productPrice": 72.38,
      "quantity": 3,
      "salesLineStatus": "Invoiced",
      "salesOrderLineId": 5637161108,
      "siteId": "GLENVW1",
      "unit": "ROLL",
      "wareHouseId": "28"
    }
  ],
  "mNoteId": null,
  "mOrderId": null,
  "notes": null,
  "orderDate": "2019-01-09",
  "orderId": 563787455,
  "orderName": "RYERSON - ELGIN #4007",
  "orderNumber": "S-0003290",
  "orderType": "Sales order",
  "requestedReceiptDate": "2019-01-10",
  "requestedShipDate": "2019-01-10",
  "salesOrderStatus": "Invoiced",
  "salesTaxTotal": 0,
  "siteId": "GLENVW1",
  "wareHouseId": "28"
}
```

---

mobile app asks for the order data , AIF webservice execute the query to fetch order details from AX and returns all the data into app. So the amount of time the webservice fetches the data from AX takes more time and result into timeout

Comment: Have you determined where is your perf problem? network? data-parsing? memory? local persistence? In our team, we developed a similar app which fetches 14K products and saves them in its local cache with no problem.

Comment: @jesus Angulo can you please share your roadmap or solution that you have applied to fetch 14k products ?

Comment: What version of dynamics are you using? Have you considered a custom web service to avoid the AIF overhead and the XML to JSON transformation? Where exactly does the timeout occur?

Comment: To add to the comments/questions here: have you researched paging at all in regards to AIF services in AX? See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/handling-large-datasets-returned-by-the-query-service

Comment: @FH-Inway we are using `Microsoft Dynamics AX R3CU11` and yes we have a webservice wrapper that converts the response into JSON and returns to the mobile app to avoid the overheads of XML. We do have implemented pagination as well while accessing the webservice from mobile